# Supabase RPC Typescript Types Nullable

Tags: typescript, function, rpc, nullable, supabase

I made a Supabase RPC function and I'm having problems with the typescript definitions generated from:

```
npx supabase gen types
```

Below are the generated types, and I want to make `current_status` nullable, as it can sometimes be missing:

```
get_bananas: {
  Args: {
    _limit?: number;
    _offset?: number;
  };
  Returns: {
    id: string;
    text: string;
    current_status: Database['public']['Enums']['status_type_enum'];
    // current_status: null | Database['public']['Enums']['status_type_enum'];
  }[];
};
```

This is my RPC function:

```
CREATE TYPE status_type_enum AS ENUM ('rotten', 'ripe'); 

CREATE FUNCTION get_bananas(
  _limit INT DEFAULT NULL,
  _offset INT DEFAULT 0
)
RETURNS TABLE (
  id UUID,
  text TEXT,
  current_status status_type_enum // How do I make this nullable in TS? 
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT
    b.id,
    b.text,
    s.status_type AS current_status
  FROM bananas b
  LEFT JOIN statuses s ON b.id = s.banana_id AND s.user_id = auth.uid()
  LIMIT _limit
  OFFSET _offset;
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

The generated typescript type should be nullable if the returned function column type is nullable. You can have your function inherit the table column type with the `[table].[column]%TYPE` notation like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_bananas(
  _limit INT DEFAULT NULL,
  _offset INT DEFAULT 0
)
RETURNS TABLE (
  id bananas.id%TYPE,
  text bananas.text%TYPE,
  current_status statuses.status_type%TYPE
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT
    b.id,
    b.text,
    s.status_type AS current_status
  FROM bananas b
  LEFT JOIN statuses s ON b.id = s.banana_id AND s.user_id = auth.uid()
  LIMIT _limit
  OFFSET _offset;
END;
$$;
```

Once you update your function definition, run the type generation again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work, `statuses.status_type` is not nullable but it can be null because it's possible to have no status for a banana (no row in the database).

Even updating the type of `statuses.status_type` to allow null and the RPC with `current_status statuses.status_type%TYPE`, the generated types for my RPC function remain the same ...

Comment: @Potato Huh, okay. I see that you tried `current_status: null | Database['public']['Enums']['status_type_enum'];`, but did that not work?

Comment: The types are generated so if I add `null` to `current_status`, it does work, but it is overwritten everytime I regenerate the types.
I thought about adding my own types to override the generated ones but I was looking into getting the right types generated right away - if that is possible.

Comment: @Potato I understand. This might be a technical limitation on the Supabase. It might help opening an issue on the Supabase CLI repo. https://github.com/supabase/cli